# PHP while loop and and finding the average of the same numbers

Tags: php

1. How to use a while loop to get the numbers that can be divided by 3 between 0 and 100?
2. Then find the average of these numbers?

This is what I thought would work in the first part, but didnt.

```
<?php
$i = 3;
while ($i < 99 && $i%3==0) {
    echo " $i <br />";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$counter = 0;
$total = 0;
while ($i < 99) {
    if($i%3==0){
      $counter++;
      $total += $i;
    } 
    $i++;
}
$average = $total/$counter;
echo $average;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [modulo operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) `%` for it. when an item is dividable by the right hand side of the modulo operator value, the result will be 0.

```
for($c=1; $c< 100; $c++) {
   if($c % 3 === 0) {
      echo "$c is dividable by 3\n";
   }
}
```

See it live: https://ideone.com/oF2C9B

Basically if you have a sum like  `A % B`
B will get substracted from A as long as it can be subtracted in whole. Whatever remains gets returned.

so if you'd do `15 % 10` you get `5` returned and if you do `30 % 10` you'd get `0` returned.

Now for the second part. You want an average of all the numbers dividable by 3 I guess from your question.

```
<?php
/**
 * We use an array to store all the numbers that can be divided by three
 */
$div_by_three = [];

/**
 * fill the array with values that can be divided by three
 */
for($c=1; $c< 100; $c++) {
   if($c % 3 === 0) {
      $div_by_three[] = $c;
   }
}
/**
 * Sum the array values into one number
 */
$sum = array_sum($div_by_three);
echo "The sum of those dividable by three is $sum\n";

/**
 * Divide the sum by array length
 */
$avg = $sum / count($div_by_three);
echo "The average of those dividable by three is $avg\n";
```

See it live: https://ideone.com/NTrH4E

Basically the methods here are [array_sum()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php), to quickly add up the array values and [count()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to get the length of the array to calculate the average.

Answer (score 0):

```
$nums = [];

foreach(range(1, 99) as $i) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        $nums[] = $i;
    }
}
$avg = array_sum($nums) / count($nums);

echo implode(', ', $nums) . '<hr>';
echo 'Average: ' . $avg;
```

If you want to be shorter:

```
$nums = array_filter(range(1, 99), function($num) {
    return $num % 3 == 0;
});
$avg = array_sum($nums) / count($nums);

echo implode(', ', $nums) . '<hr>';
echo 'Average: ' . $avg;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second question:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$cnt = 0;
$sum = 0;
while ($i < 99) {
    if($i%3==0) {
        echo $i . "</br>";
        $cnt++;
        $sum += $i;
    }
    $i++;
}
$avg = $sum / $cnt;
echo "Average: $avg";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $i = 3;
    while ($i < 99 ) {

        if ($i%3==0 ){
            $total = ($i+3)/3;
        }

        $i++;
    }
    echo $total;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your first attempt did not work is because the loop conditional is only valid when `$i` is a multiple of three.  That will no longer be valid on the second iteration.  In English:

```
$i = 3

# Iteration 1
is 3 less than 99 AND 3 an even divisor of 3?  YES
  do loop, and increment $i to 4.

# Iteration 2
is 4 less than 99 AND 4 an even divisor of 3?  NO
```

The trick as the other answers has pointed out, is be clear about what role each part performs.  The `while` loop's sole purpose is to increment `$i` *while $i is less than 99*.  Thus, the conditional checks exactly one detail: "Is $i less than 99?"

Meanwhile, for the higher level question you want to answer, you can use an if-conditional inside the loop.

```
$i = 3;
$totalSum = 0;
$numDivisableByThree = 0;
while ( $i < 99 ) {
    if ( ($i % 3) == 0 ) {
        $totalSum += $i;
        $numDivisableByThree++;
    }
    $i++;
}

# careful, ensure that your algorithm found at least one item, else
# you may attempt a divide by zero
if ( $numDivisableByThree > 0 )
    $myAverage = $totalSum / $numDivisableByThree;
else
    $myAverage = "No Average (0 items found)";  # or perhaps false or null;

echo "Average of 3-divisable numbers between 1 and 99: $myAverage";
```

I suppose this is a simple project, but also recognize that the simple "brute-force" checking is very inefficient to calculate.  Consider the better method of simply adding 3 each iteration:

```
$i = 3
...
while ( $i < 99 ) {
    $totalSum += $i;
    $numDivisableByThree++;
    $i += 3
}
...
```

(Note the lack of need for the internal `if` conditional).

Or better yet, use an algorithm to count directly:

```
$beg = 3;
$end = 99;  # ensure that 
$divisor = 3;
# if $beg is divisible by $divisor, then it won't be counted by the math;
# therefore, add 1 explicitly
if ($beg % $divisor == 0)
    return ((int)($end / $divisor)) - ((int)($beg / $divisor)) + 1;

return ((int)($end / $divisor)) - ((int)($beg / $divisor));
```

Comment: Thank you for a very informative response and for the time you have spent!